# Why use a function rather than a reference to member?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, reference

I was just testing looking through some code and noticed something similar to:

```
template<typename T>
class example{
    public:
        example(T t): m_value{t}{}

        const T &value = m_value;

    private:
        T m_value;
};
```

I haven't seen this before. Almost every API or library I've used before defines a function that returns a member variable like so, and not a constant reference to it:

```
template<typename T>
class example{
    public:
        example(T t): m_value{t}{}

        const T &value() const{
            return m_value;
        }

    private:
        T m_value;
};
```

Why is the first way less common? What are the disadvantages?

Comment: it just style. some people just hate any kind of public member and some think its fine if they are immutable / const

Comment: One major difference is that in the second version, the caller can't use the reference to modify `m_value`. And it'd be easy to upgrade the function to do some checking or pre-getting actions. And prior to C++11 you'd have to init the reference in all the constructors, which is tedious.

Comment: Also, the second one results in objects being smaller

Comment: @MattMcNabb what makes you say that they can edit the `m_value` through the `const &` in the first example?

Comment: `const_cast<T &>(value) = x;`

Comment: I'll remember that :L seems like such an evil feature

Comment: @Deduplicator Unions have fairly significant restrictions on their members. They should in general be used only for POD types and thus may not be applicable in the case of a general class template like this.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Both styles allow modifying the member via `const_cast`.

Comment: When I wrote my comment , the second one was `const T value() const { return  m_value; }`. He modified it to return a reference after that.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There are a few reasons why (inline) functions that return an appropriate reference are better:

1. A reference will require memory (typically the same amount as a pointer) in each object
2. References typically have the same alignment as pointers, thus causing the surrounding object to potentially require a higher alignment and thus wasting even more memory
3. Initializing a reference requires (a minuscule amount of) time
4. Having a member field of reference type will disable the default copy and move assignment operators since references are not reseatable
5. Having a member field of reference type will cause the automatically generated default copy and move constructors to be incorrect, since they will now contain references to the members of other objects
6. Functions can do additional checking like verifying invariants in debug builds

Be aware that due to inlining, the function will usually not incur any extra costs beyond a potentially slightly larger binary.

Comment: Requiring more memory for the same functionality is not usually wanted?

Comment: @Deduplicator `const T &value = m_value;` is a member variable of type `T const&`?

Comment: @CoffeeandCode I think number 5 is the real killer (and without your comment I would have left it wrong ^^)

Comment: I'd just like to add, the example doesn't return a copy anymore; to make the two examples more similar.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that might be a typo ;)

Comment: Personally I find point 6 to be the most problematic on the long term. The point of using a function here is actually because of evolution of the code. Each time there is a possible improvement or necessary change to the type, and we need to add code to the accessor, if the accessor was a reference or even a public object, then we need to change it to a function, therefore breaking the interface of the type and having to also change all the code that uses that member. Just for maintainability sake of big code bases, it becomes common sense that the function is the most future proof interface.

Comment: @Klaim You may be able to maintain the interface by changing the reference to a reference-like object, which effectively already works like a property ;)

Comment: @dionadar Indeed, that's one of the "hacks" that is possible to implement property-like libraries, but they all have issues regarding their interface and how they can be used in expression. Unfortunately, a property system have to be implemented as a language feature to be definitely useful. I am not personally for or against this kind of feature by the way. I know there is discussions to provide it as a side effect of other proposals for C++.

Answer (score 3):

Encapsulation.

For Object-Oriented Programming purists, `m_value` is an implementation detail. Consumers of class `example` should be able to use a single reliable interface to access `value()` and shouldn't be dependent on how `example` happens to determine it. A future version of `example` (or an complicated template specialization) might want to use caching or logging before returning a `value()`; or it might need to calculate `value()` on the fly  because of memory constraints.

If you don't use an accessor function originally, everything that uses `example` might have to change if you change your mind later. And that can introduce all kinds of waste and bugs. It's easier to just abstract it one level further by providing an accessor like `value()`.

On the other hand, some people just aren't as rigid about those kinds of OOP principles and just like to write code that's efficient and legible, dealing with refactoring when it happens.

Answer (score 2):

The first option requires extra memory, just like a pointer.

If you do:

```
inline const T& value() const{
      return m_value;
}
```

you have the same benefit than the first approach without the need of extra memory.

Also, since the first approach needs C++11, it will be less likely that people use it.

Comment: Wouldn't you need the required memory for a reference when returning one?

Comment: @CoffeeandCode: Only on the stack for the split second that the function executes.  The first version has that reference inside of every instance of every object at all times.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode Also, since it is inlineable, the compiler may optimize and use no extra memory, accessing directly the object member. With the first approach this kind of optimization is not possible because the compiler can not foresee (at least not easily) that the reference is pointing to that actual member.

Answer (score 1):

General use for returning const references:
Returning a constant reference is common for cases where creating or destroying a copy is expensive.
In general, the rule is: If passing and using a reference is more expensive than making a copy, don't do so. If you were not asked for a subobject, it is normally even impossible.
Otherwise, it's a valid performance-optimization to return constant references, which is transparent to well-behaved source-code.
Much template code returns constant references even where the above test does not indicate, just to treat all specialisations equally and because the function is really small and is nearly guaranteed to be inlined anyway.

Now, to the meat of your curious find (never saw its like yet):
+ No need for an accessor function (still, this is lame, it will be compiled out anyway)
- The object is bigger (references normally need as much space as pointers)
- Potentially need better alignment due to the above point.
- Has no magic member functions, because the compiler does not know how to copy references
- For debug builds, one cannot add additional checks.

The same look&feel without that collateral damage can be achieved like this btw (only additional checks for debug stay impossible):

```
template<typename T>
struct example {
    example(T t): value{t}{}
    union{
        const T value;
        struct{
        private:
            T value;
            friend class example<T>;
        } _value;
    };
};
```